# FormGroup values are not updated after setValue inside subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have custom radio list with different control name for each control (these controls are checkboxes in html) The think is from list of these checkboxes (inputs names) only one can be selected and I do something like this (in ngOnInit):

```js
formGroup
  .get('ChildGroup')
  .valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(formGroup.get('ChildGroup').getRawValue()),
    pairwise(),
  )
  .subscribe(([oldState, newState]) => {
    console.log(oldState, newState)
    // List of radio checkboxes
    const radioInputs = [
      'childName1', 'childName2', 'childName3', 'childName4',
    ];
    // Find changed value
    const updatedElementName = radioInputs.find(
      elem => oldState[elem] !== newState[elem],
    );
    // Set true only for input which is changed
    radioInputs.forEach(input => {
      formGroup
        .get('ChildGroup')
        .get(input)
        .setValue(
          updatedElementName === input, { emitEvent: false },
        );
    });
  });
```

Problem is weird because after clicking on checkboxes I received data like this from logs:

```js
// First click on childName2 (childName1 unchecked) - correct, expected
oldState.childName1 // true
oldState.childName2 // false
newState.childName1 // true
newState.childName2 // true

// Second click on childName1 (childName1 and childName2 unchecked)
oldState.childName1 // true
oldState.childName2 // true
newState.childName1 // true
newState.childName2 // true
```

oldState.childName1 value in second click is not false as expected, even if I used setValue on false in valueChanges subscribtion after first click.

Stackblitz with this bug:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9ppdt

- Angular 7.2
- RxJS 6.3

If my description is not clear, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to recreate the problem inside a stackblitz or JSfiddle?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9ppdt

Answer (score 2):

this can be a simple solution , just subscribe to value change foreach control and flip the other control value

```
this.formGroup.get('control1').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.formGroup.get('control2').setValue(!value, { emitEvent: false })
})

this.formGroup.get('control2').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.formGroup.get('control1').setValue(!value, { emitEvent: false })
})
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw1y84)

Updated!
base of the same ideam as above but as dynamic subscribe base of array of controls

in case I have this list of controls

```
  radioInputs = [
    'control1', 'control2', 'control3', 'control4', 'control5'
  ];
```

subscribe for each form controls,everytime any of the controls checked reset the other controls

```
this.radioInputs.forEach(control => {
  this.formGroup.get(control).valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (value) {
      this.resetOthers(control);
    }
  })
});
```

reset method

```
  resetOthers(currentControl) {
    this.radioInputs.filter(control => control !== currentControl).forEach(control => {
      this.formGroup.get(control).setValue(false, { emitEvent: false })
    })
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agvxnh)

Comment: What if we want to unselect all options?

Comment: @JoeyGough you can use reset method , I have update the demo

Comment: how easily does it scale to four or five options?

Comment: @JoeyGough your key goal is to toggle the other controls rights  like the first true all others is false ?

Comment: @JoeyGough in case of five is uncheck one will tregger the other to be checked ?

Comment: @JoeyGough thank for the feedback I manage to update the answer 

Comment: Nice one, looks much better. You should use a *ngFor loop over your radioControls array to render the html inputs `<input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let control of radioInputs" [formControlName]="control">`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the technicalities of your question per se, but I achieved what you are trying to achieve here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1vj53

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { mergeMap, pairwise, startWith, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface RadioControl {
  title: string;
  initialValue: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  formGroup: FormGroup

  public controls: RadioControl[] = [
    {
      title: 'control1',
      initialValue: true
    },
    {
      title: 'control2',
      initialValue: false
    },
    {
      title: 'control3',
      initialValue: false
    },
    {
      title: 'control4',
      initialValue: false
    }
  ]

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {

  }
  handleInputClick(controlName: string): void {
    // remove this if block if you wish not allow all blank inputs and always have one selected
    // This allows to unselect all
    if (this.formGroup.get(controlName).value) {
      this.formGroup.get(controlName).setValue(false);
      return;
    }
    Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls).forEach((e: string) => {
      this.formGroup.get(e).setValue(e === controlName);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const groupInitObj = {}
    this.controls.forEach((e: RadioControl) => {
      groupInitObj[e.title] = this.fb.control(e.initialValue);
    });
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group(groupInitObj);
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input *ngFor="let control of controls" (click)="handleInputClick(control.title)" type="checkbox" [formControlName]="control.title">
</form>
```

Comment:  both of our answes are some how about that same idea I use valueChange and you just add the click method